# Bounded gradient

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function (my function is $C^2$ and satisfies the heat equation), but I think $C^1$ is enough for this question) with the property that $|u|\rightarrow 0$ when $|x|\to\infty$. Is there a way to conclude that the gradient of $u$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under these conditions, no. Take for example
$$
u(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1x\sin(x^3),&x\neq0\\
0,&x=0
\end{cases}
$$
This function is smooth (in fact real analytic) and $u(x)\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$ but $u'(x)=3x\cos(x^3)-x^{-2}\sin(x^3)$ is unbounded.